# i have problem in generating release apk i get AAPT error

Tags: android

`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception:AAPT error:` check logs for details.
how to solved it*

Comment: any one give me answer please

Comment: have you read **`check logs for details.`**

Comment: We can't tell only because you copy paster the error... Some code / stacktrace would be helpful. What you just did, you could have done on google (and get more ideas about it)

Comment: please include logcat

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it occurs with classpath. Try to check gradle classpath

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google() 
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google() // important!
    jcenter()
}
}
```